# Tkinter wm_attributes does not have all the options in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, user-interface, tkinter

I wanted to create a GUI with Tkinter in Linux (*Python3.x*). When I tried to execute the following: -

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter


root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True) # Hide the cross button and that bar
root.wait_visibility(root)
root.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-transparent", "true")



root_w = 190
root_h = 190

win_w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
win_h = root.winfo_screenheight()


root.geometry(f'{root_w}x{root_h}+{win_w - root_w - 40}+{win_h - root_h - 40}')



samplabl = Button(root, text=f"WIDTH: {win_w} HEIGHT: {win_h}", bg='#ffffff')

samplabl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is what I get: -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bravo6/Desktop/Stella__Compilative/GUI/temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    root.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-transparent", "true")
_tkinter.TclError: bad attribute "-transparent": must be -alpha, -topmost, -zoomed, -fullscreen, or -type
```

Looks like the `wm_attribute` didn't recognise the `-transparent` attribute... It seemed that it only works in Windows. Any idea how to get this working in Linux?

Comment: O think when it comes to some properties, they may not be available on some OS.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm), `-transparent` is only supported for Macs. If you just want a transparent/see-through window, maybe play with `-alpha`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing you can do. Different operating systems support different options for the window manager. As of the time I write this, these are the supported attributes for each windowing system:

**All platforms**: `alpha`, `fullscreen`, `topmost`
**OSX**: `modified`, `notify`, `titlepath`, `transparent`
**Windows**: `disabled`, `toolwindow`, `transparentcolor`
**X11-based systems** (ie: linux, and only with some window managers) : `type`, `zoomed`

Comment: Yeah... I figured as much! I kinda tweaked around but still it didn't work... Thanks a lot though!